# Azure Powershell, unable to scroll up after a certain extend

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

How could I increase the history of the `powershell`? What i mean by the history of the `powershell` here is that, to increase the scrolling up feature.

I tried increasing the `Buffer Size` within the `Properties` but it didn't work out. What should I do to make the `powershell` let me keep scrolling towards up to view what I've done? I know that I could simply get the `history` of the commands by typing in this command: `Get-History`, but what if I wanted to see some outputs?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The maximum you can scroll on a powershell windows is 9999 lines.

[image]

If you want to log all things which happens in a session, you can do the below.

Once you open a new session, provide the below command

```
Start-Transcript -Path "[YourPath]\PowershellSession.log"
```

This will ensure all the actions you perform and see in the window is logged to the log file. You can use the -Append parameter to add the log to an existing file as well.

Note: I think this does not work in Powershell ISE

Hope this helps.

Comment: This question's title states that this is for Azure, and the window in the screenshot here is for Windows.  Additionally, the command you provided does not capture output messages which contribute to the buffer.